# Magento 2 install issues

Tags: installation, magento2

```
Magento 2.0.x 

Installation problem for 2nd web nodes ,i already copy whole Magento docroot to new server ... please help and instruct .
```

There has been an error processing your request

Requested store is not found

Error log record number: 650496116931

Comment: please check var/report/650496116931 for more details, as you said that you've just transferred your magento root to a new server then i guess there might have a database connection problem. Check your DB credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout your error log file under the var/report folder. Under this file you will get the exact issue so it can help you to figure out the exact issue.